Is there a way to throw an error instead of a warning?
I am working on a test script of a package we are developing and I kinda got stuck with this.
I have a function which takes multiple formula (I won't go into details..) and want to test if the function can return an error when formula has invalid covariates. Specifically I am stuck with this case where covariate is a factor but squared (I know it does not work).
simple example
xxx <- function(formula){
  ....
}

n <- as.factor(1:3)
formula <- ~ I(n ^ 2)
xxx(n)

and this returns a warning
Warning message:
In Ops.factor(n, 2) : ‘^’ not meaningful for factors

it is because of this
> I(n ^ 2)
[1] NA NA NA
Warning message:
In Ops.factor(n, 2) : ‘^’ not meaningful for factors

but because I(n^2) returns NAs with a warning not an error, function returns a error in unexpected place where it cannot process with NAs.
Can anyone help me with I(n^2) evaluations to stop when argument is invalid (this case, factor) and returns with an error instead of giving NAs and warning message?
Also, this function is a part of bigger function so the formula argument takes in a form of ~ + xxx + yyy.

fac <- factor(1:3)
fac ^ 2
#Warning message:
#In Ops.factor(fac, 2) : ‘^’ not meaningful for factors

#turn all warnings into errors
globalCallingHandlers(warning = stop)
fac ^ 2
#Error in Ops.factor(fac, 2) : ‘^’ not meaningful for factors
globalCallingHandlers(NULL)

#only turn warnings for specific call into errors
tryCatch(fac ^ 2, warning = \(w) stop(w))
#Error in Ops.factor(fac, 2) : ‘^’ not meaningful for factors

